# Emulator: The system cannot find the path specified Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-emulator

I am trying to install flutter SDK in my Android Studio. Everything is fine the SDK path, environment variables, etc. But still, I am facing this issue. The project is also not running. 
[image: THis the error I am facing.]

Comment: did you add flutter to your enviroment variable?

Comment: Yes I had add all the variables of JAVA_HOME & ANDROID

Answer (score 0):

Did you swap(clone disk)?

I had the same problem, now I had to back to old drive, because flutter keep working with that drive and doesn't work with new drive, both are external